# Merging two lists into one in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to merge two lists into one under one condition?

I have list of lists where I have name, email address and item purchased for each customer.

Some customers purchased two items and thus have the same email, but no name indicated as separate list.

How can I add their second purchased item into the first list with their names?

I have following:

```
['Heather Holt', 'ht*****r1011@gmail.com', 'Lite-Lounge - White']
['', 'ht*****r1011@gmail.com', 'Lite-Desk - Oyster Grey']
```

I want to see the lists in the following way:

```
['Heather Holt', 'ht*****r1011@gmail.com', 'Lite-Lounge - White', 'Lite-Desk - Oyster Grey']
```

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Would it be easier to use some other datatype, for example, dict to store the name, email and list of products?

Comment: If I use dictionary, I don't think I can add second value to product name?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `dict` to store your data. You could have a dict like

```
customer = { "name": "Heather Holt", "email": "ht*****r1011@gmail.com", products: ["Lite-Lounge - White"]

customer["products"].append("Lite-Desk - Oyster Grey")

print(customer["products"])
```

#### Output

```
["Lite-Lounge - White", "Lite-Desk - Oyster Grey"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense. Will try this way.